# Android offline documentation and sample code

Tags: android, documentation, offline

I am not able to find the offline docs for Android. Can someone provide a link?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you install the SDK, the offline documentation can be found in `$ANDROID_SDK/docs/`.

Comment: Cheers, saves time even on a wide broadband. And finally I can browse it while on a train. Search in docs redirects online though :(

Comment: It seems that in the recent versions of the Android SDK, documentation is not included in the download. It is not available in the version 17 (20130219).

Comment: I can confirm it is not available in version 18 either. I am using Android Studio, not the eclipse ide android download.

Comment: For a searchable offline documentation for Android and 130+ APIs and languages, check: Zeal (zealdocs.org) for Linux and Windows or Dash (kapeli.com/dash) for Mac.

Comment: where do you install the sdk from? did a google search, nothing clear popped up

Comment: Ensure to download documentation in Android Studio's SDK Manager. Because other than that you won't read from SDK/Docs

Comment: @malhobayyeb Now Zeal are supporting macOs

Answer (score 37):

This thread is a little old, and I am brand new to this, but I think I found the preferred solution.

First, I assume that you are using Eclipse and the Android ADT plugin.

In Eclipse, choose Window/Android SDK Manager.  In the display, expand the entry for the MOST RECENT PLATFORM, even if that is not the platform that your are developing for.  As of Jan 2012, it is "Android 4.0.3 (API 15)".  When expanded, the first entry is "Documentation for Android SDK"  Click the checkbox next to it, and then click the "Install" button.

When done, you should have a new directory in your "android-sdks" called "doc".  Look for "offline.html" in there.  Since this is packaged with the most recent version, it will document the most recent platform, but it should also show the APIs for previous versions.

Comment: And if you aren't using Eclipse, just run android.bat or 'SDK Manager.exe'.

Comment: +1 for the CLEAN solution.

Answer (score 31):

here is direct link for api 17 documentation. Just extract at under docs folder. Hope it helps.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-17_r02.zip   (129 MB)

Comment: Here's the latest version (Sept 2013): [docs-18_r01.zip](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-18_r01.zip)

Comment: is there any newer version ?

Comment: @Omid : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-19_r02.zip

Comment: great, this still works.. :) 

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-22_r01.zip

Comment: New version for Android 6.0: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-23_r01.zip

Comment: Doesn't work any more for API 25. Can someone please provide an updated link?

Comment: v24 is the latest I have seen. By the way, why are we using the comments section of this answer to update for each new version? It's funny how this has been going for 4 years now. This question should just be re-opened and updated instead of this flaky update via these comments.

Comment: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml

Answer (score 22):

At first choose your API level from the following links:

**API Level 17:** http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-17_r02.zip

**API Level 18:** http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-18_r02.zip

**API Level 19:** http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-19_r02.zip

**Android-L API doc:** http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-L_r01.zip

**API Level 24 doc:** https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-24_r01.zip

download and extract it in your sdk driectory.

**In your eclipse IDE:**

at `project -> properties -> java build path -> Libraries -> Android x.x -> android.jar -> javadoc`

press edit in right:

```
javadoc URL -> Browse
```

select "docs/***reference/***" in archive extracted directory

press `validate`... to validate this javadoc.

**In your IntelliJ IDEA**

at `file -> Project Structure`
Select SDKs from left panel -> select your sdk from middle panel -> in right panel go to `Documentation Paths` tab so click plus icon and select `docs/reference/` in archive extracted directory.

enjoy the offline javadoc...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the latest version of Android Studio (2.3). Any idea how to find the setting to set the docs path there?

Comment: You'r right, this answer well for older version of android studio. In newer versions you should just download documents according to your project `compileSdkVersion` by SDK Manager.

Answer (score 5):

Write the following in linux terminal:

```
$ wget -r http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html
```

Answer (score 4):

First of All you should download the Android SDK.
Download here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Then, as stated in the SDK README:

> The Android SDK archive now only
>   contains the tools. It no longer comes
>   populated with a specific Android
>   platform or Google add-on. Instead you
>   use the SDK Manager to install or
>   update SDK components such as
>   platforms, tools, add-ons, and
>   **documentation**.

Comment: I have a small question. Do you know how i can transfer the docs folder into my ipad and read the docs offline? What app allows me to do so?

Comment: As of AS 4.0, I find no option to download the documentation in the SDK Manager.  If it is thtere, where is it?