# Android API guides (with figures) for offline use

Tags: android, api, download, offline

I'm looking for a possibility to browse the android API guides offline (with figures). I read several questions about this here (ex. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898053/android-offline-documentation-and-sample-codes), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937184/where-can-i-download-the-android-sdk-documentation), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811745/where-can-i-download-the-api-docs-for-android)...) and tried to get offline docs from the sdk folder or using a direct link. The problem with the actual version (23_r01) is that the images are often not displayed. For example in the page `sdk/docs/design/index.html` the image `hero-material-design.png` could not be displayed because of a bad `src` tag.

What I've tried:

1. Using the docs from the SDK folder
2. Direct download from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-23_r01.zip
3. Saving the files using HTTrack (I'm getting errors here..)

What I would like to achive:

- Download a correct version of the docs
- **OR** "Repair" all the broken image paths in the html files

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If thats still interested to you, just edit `\docs\design\index.html`, add .. before /design (it means the parent folder, one dot means the current), like that:

`<img class="dac-hero-image" src="../design/media/hero-material-design.png">`