# How to use Android SDK Documentation offline

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I've downloaded Android SDK Documentation using SDK Manager, to use it with Android Studio v2.3.0.8, offline.

But everytime I press ctrl+q to show quick info about a type|type-member, it shows "Fetching Documentation...", and after waiting for ~20s, it shows the info.

I don't want that delay or using online help, and the local docs are in place, so why is that ?
And what is the solution ?

Edit: **This happens when I'm online, but no delay at all when I'm offline**, 
*As if the IDE tries to get a fresh version of docs.*

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? In 2.3 this just works. I do not get any delay.

Comment: My Windows is on ssd, I don't think its a slow hdd problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I found in the comment of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16363093/7736965, that other people are having same|similar issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio quick documentation always "fetching documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Improved solution for displaying documentation (from sources).**

Found, that if you download documentation via SDK manager (it will be located in `.../sdk/docs/reference`), you're going to use `only 24 API documentation`. (Imagine, your project target SDK is 25 or 22, for instance).

[image: Only 24 API in downloaded documentation]

To fix this, you need:

1. Delete documentation via SDK manager in Android Studio.
   [image: Delete documenattion in SDK manager]
2. Right there, download sources for interested APIs (sources already contain documentation). Also I found, that fetching `documentation from sources` a bit faster comparing with offline one inside `.../sdk/docs/reference`.
   [image: Download sources via SDK manager for interested APIs]
3. Delete all javadoc paths from `jdk.table.xml`. Path to this file on OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio.../options/jdk.table.xml`

   ```
   --> Delete all of these and all occurrences -->

   <javadocPath>
     <root type="composite">
       <root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" />
     </root>
   </javadocPath>
   ```
4. Reboot Studio. Enjoy!

Comment: You can use SDK Documentation for projects targeting different API, `not only 24 API` if you follow [Mauricio answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005110/3268088).

Your solution works, but I didn't download api-24 platform or sources, just api-25 platform and source.

Comment: a `sed` oneliner to delete all the *javadocPath* blocks (on macos): `sed -i.bak '/<javadocPath>/,/<\/javadocPath>/d'   ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.5/options/jdk.table.xml` (you might want to make a backup first because the file will be modified in-place)

Answer (score 18):

I downloaded it too, and I noticed that the Android Studio didn't generated the `javadocPath` properly in `jdk.table.xml`, that's how the file looks like (part that has the `jdk` tag with the name `Android API ## Platform`):

```xml
...
<jdk version="2">
  <name value="Android API 25 Platform" />
  <type value="Android SDK" />
  <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/android-sdk" />
  <roots>
      ...
    <javadocPath>
      <root type="composite">
        <root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" />
      </root>
    </javadocPath>
      ...
```

> File is located at [`Android Studio Configuration folder`](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#file_location)`/config/options/jdk.table.xml`

Notice that the `javadocPath` is pointing to the online url, just change that to your local copy, in my case, the `docs` folder is in `/home/mauricio/android-sdk/docs`, in Windows is something like `C:/android-sdk/docs`.

The url structure that you have to follow is `file://<path-to-sdk>/docs/reference`

> You **have** to point to the `reference` folder inside the docs.

It'll look something like this:

```xml
  <root type="simple" url="file:///home/mauricio/android-sdk/docs/reference" />
  <!-- if it's Windows -->
  <root type="simple" url="file://C:/android-sdk/docs/reference" />
```

Then, if it's running, restart the Android Studio and it's done.
I have a SSD too, and the offline documentation makes it open instantly.

**Note:** You have to do that in all `javadocPath` in the file (pretty easy using `Replace all` in any text editor), and when you download a new Android API, you have to do that again because it generates the url pointing to the online docs.

---

I think this is a bug in Android Studio, because the `sourcePath` and `classPath` is detected and generated correctly. It's worth reporting to them.

Answer (score 3):

One way to fix `config/options/jdk.table.xml` is to stop the IDE, delete the file, ad restart. The IDE finds the installed SDKs, and it regenerates the options file.

I had issues with an upgrade from a preview release to 3.2 and docs were slow to display, and the above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For sdk tools v26, using the command-line:

```
PATH_TO_SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager "docs"
```

Then go to the directory PATH_TO_SDK/docs and open *index.html* file.

Comment: Thanks for providing the cmdline to download the docs instead of the GUI way

Comment: `Warning: Failed to find package 'docs'`. Using `sdkmanager --version; 5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the offline docs on [Android SDK Offline](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-offline-documentation-download.html)

Then unzip the tar folder Android.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.android.com to sdk/docs.

Then you can use the offline docs in AndroidStudio, but there is a little bug, the style of web is not right.